# Differences between $\beta^\text{OLS}$ and $\beta^\text{ARCH}$

Tags: least-squares, garch, finance

Consider the market model for security $i$,
$$
R_{i,t} = \alpha_i + \beta_i R_{m,t} + e_i.
$$
With daily frequency, the error term has an ARCH pattern, so I use ARCH(1) or GARCH(1,1) models, whereas at monthly frequency, OLS estimates work fine.

**Question 1:** Is it appropriate to compare these two values ($\beta^\text{OLS}$ and $\beta^\text{ARCH}$)? Or should I compare both only using the OLS method and disregard any potential issues with the error term?

**Question 2:** Is it normal that $\beta^\text{ARCH}$ is way lower than $\beta^\text{OLS}$? for example, for the same security, I got $\beta^\text{OLS}=1.12$ and $\beta^\text{ARCH}=0.90$.